# Turtle Java squares Pyramid

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I have to make a pyramid that can have its parameters changed, but my code keeps not allowing the next row after to start at the proper point, I need help! I'm sorry if its messy, I'm very new. picture at bottom is result. I need it to be centered.

```java
public class Pyramid2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Turtle t = new Turtle();
        t.delay(100);
        pyramid(t, 200, 5);
    }

    public static void square(Turtle t, double base, int levels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            t.left(90);
        }
    }

    public static void pyramid(Turtle t, double base, int levels) {
        //for (int p = 1; (p-1)< levels; p++){
        for (int j = 0; j < levels; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((levels) * 2) - (j * 2) - 1; i++) {
                square(t, base, levels);
                t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            }

            t.penup();
            t.left(90);
            t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            t.right(90);

            t.backward(base - (base / (((levels * 2) - (j * 2)) - 1)));

            t.pendown();
        }
    }
}
```

[what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ2k7.png)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out how to set up a turtle Java environment (link to a guide in the comments would be appreciated!), but the basic algorithm is pretty much language-agnostic. I'll use JavaScript with `var` so it should be compatible with Java 10+.

I'm not sure if your turtle has `goto`, but if it does, that makes rewinding to the left side of the canvas to prepare the next row easier. I'll assume you don't have this and only use `forward`, `right`, `pendown` and `penup` commands.

My approach is this:

- Set `size` and `levels` constants which represent the box/grid size and number of levels, respectively. (If you want to use `base`, fine--compute `size = base / (levels * 2 - 1)` as you've already done, but save it in a variable).
- Start from the top level
- For each level `i`:

  - Compute the number of boxes for the level: `boxes = i * 2 + 1`
  - Compute the left x-offset to start drawing boxes from: `offset = (levels - i - 1) * size`
  - Move forward `offset` pixels
  - Draw the boxes for the level
  - Move to the beginning of the next line and point rightward (`goto(0, turtle.y + size)` would be handy here to avoid some maneuvering)

Here's the code:

```js
var size = 20;
var levels = 5;
var t = new Turtle();
t.penup();

for (var i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
  var boxes = i * 2 + 1;
  var offset = (levels - i - 1) * size;
  t.forward(offset);
  t.pendown();

  for (var j = 0; j < boxes; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
      t.forward(size);
      t.right(90);
    }

    t.forward(size);
  }

  t.penup();
  t.right(90);
  t.forward(size);
  t.right(90);
  t.forward(offset + size * boxes);
  t.right(180);
}








///////////////////////////////////////
// turtle library; ignore code below //
function Turtle() {
  const rad = d => d * Math.PI / 180;
  const canvas = document.querySelector("#turtle-pond");
  canvas.width = innerWidth;
  canvas.height = innerHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);
  let x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;
  let penDown = true;
  return {
    pendown() {
      penDown = true;
    },
    penup() {
      penDown = false;
    },
    forward(dist) {
      if (penDown) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
      }

      x += Math.cos(rad(angle)) * dist;
      y += Math.sin(rad(angle)) * dist;

      if (penDown) {
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    },
    right(ang) {
      angle += ang;
    },
    left(ang) {
      angle -= ang;
    },
  };
}
```

```html
<canvas id="turtle-pond"></canvas>
```