# Creating Bricks with Turtle Python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i'm very new to programming and in here i'm supposed to create a pyramid shape of bricks where the edge of the pyramid is filled with one color and the inside of it is filled with random colors, but i can't seem to figure it out how to move the bricks to create a new row, column and the random colors specified only to inside bricks of the pyramid. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance. This is my code and it's still working for one brick only:

```
import turtle
import math
import random

bottom_brick = 10
top_brick = 1
brick_length = 35
brick_width = 25

from turtle import *
from turtle import Screen
screen = Screen()  
screen.bgcolor('white')

turtle.speed('fastest')

penup ()
goto(0, -100)
pendown()
fillcolor('#BC4A3C')
begin_fill()

#bottom_brick and top_brick are inputs from the user 
#to indicate how many bricks are used for the bottom layer and the top layer
# brick_length and brick_width are also input from user


for i in range (0, bottom_brick):
    turtle.setposition(0.5 * (i % 2), i)
   
    for j in range(i, bottom_brick):
        forward(brick_length)
        left(90)
        forward(brick_width)
        left(90)
        forward(brick_length)
        left(90)
        forward(brick_width)
        left(90)
        end_fill()
    done()
```

Comment: This code doesn't run -- the imports seem kind of messed up, and various values aren't defined.  Could you update the code so it's runnable?  (Just add `brick_length = 100` or whatever to give examples of reasonable values.)

Comment: All you need to do, I think, is put your brick-drawing code in a function so you can call it multiple times in a pyramid pattern, but it's hard to demonstrate if the existing code to draw a brick doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: @Samwise Hi, sorry i didn't post all of my code previously. i have updated my code

Comment: What's the pyramid of bricks supposed to look like? Do you have a reference image? Is it something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73707326/6243352) (aside from colors; deal with that once you have the bricks drawn)? You seem to understand how to use loops. Can you apply the loop to draw multiple rows of bricks?

Comment: What's `t.numinput`?  What values would you be entering into that function if it existed? 
 Again: *It would be easier for you to just hard-code the values into your test case so that the script will run exactly the same way for us as it does for you.*  You should also ***run your test case yourself** before putting it in your question to make sure it actually runs.*

Comment: @ggorlen hi, unfortunately i am not qualified enough to post a picture directly here so i'll attach a link in my gdrive:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R0PR14CjsdoIQE9nrOkP4MKeFnpyr7fT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks--the algorithm in the link should work for this use case, with the slight adjustment that you'll need to offset the brick by half its width, alternating per row, and draw 1 extra box per row. I second the suggestion to hardcode the values and don't worry about the input until the end. It slows development and makes it hard to reproduce and get on the same page when working with others.

Comment: @Samwise , hi i'm incredibly sorry, i have hard-coded my values now and run the test case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you most of the way there with regards to making sure your bricks are laid out correctly:

```
import turtle

bottom_brick = 10
top_brick = 1
brick_length = 35
brick_width = 25


turtle.Screen().bgcolor('white')
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0, -100)
turtle.pendown()


#bottom_brick and top_brick are inputs from the user 
#to indicate how many bricks are used for the bottom layer and the top layer
# brick_length and brick_width are also input from user


for i in range(bottom_brick - top_brick + 2):
    for j in range(bottom_brick - i + 1):
        turtle.setposition((j + i / 2) * brick_length, i * brick_width)
        turtle.fillcolor('#BC4A3C')
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(brick_length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(brick_width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(brick_length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(brick_width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

Note that the fill color needs to be set inside the loop, and that's the spot where you'll want to randomize the color so that each brick is different.  You'll also need to be mindful of when the pen is up and when it's down in order to avoid extra lines showing up.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the help. One question, is there any way i can get rid of the line that connects the turtle in every row of the pyramid?

Comment: That's what I was referring to when I said you need to be mindful of when the pen is down and up.  :)  Right now you just set the pen down before you start drawing and leave it down the entire time; you need to instead figure out how to only have it down while it's drawing the brick pattern, and raise it when you're repositioning to the next brick.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an opportunity for better living through *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

top_brick = 1
bottom_brick = 10
brick_length = 35
brick_width = 25

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(brick_width / CURSOR_SIZE, brick_length / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()
turtle.sety((bottom_brick - top_brick + 1) * brick_width / -2)

for row in range(bottom_brick, top_brick - 1, -1):
    turtle.goto(-brick_length * (row / 2), turtle.ycor() + brick_width)

    for column in range(row):
        if top_brick < row < bottom_brick and 0 < column < row - 1:
            turtle.fillcolor(random(), random(), random())
        else:
            turtle.fillcolor('#BC4A3C')

        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(brick_length)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Plus an example of how you might handle the brick coloring issue.