# Im trying to create a square pyramid using turtle graphics, but the turtle doesn't position itself correctly to start the next row

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a square pyramid (pictured below):

[image]

But with the following code this is the result:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated! (note: I can't use the "goTo" command)

My code:

```
class Pyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Turtle t = new Turtle();
        t.delay(100);
        pyramid(t, 200, 5);
    }

    public static void pyramid(Turtle t, double base, int levels) {
        for (int j=0; j<levels; j++) {
            for (int i=0; i<((levels) * 2) - 1 - (j * 2); i++) {
                square(t, base, levels);
                t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            }

            t.penup();
            t.backward(base - ((base / ((levels * 2) - 1)) * (j * 2)));
            t.left(90);
            t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            t.right(90);
            t.pendown();
        }
    }

    public static void square(Turtle t, double base, int levels) {
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            t.forward(base / ((levels * 2) - 1));
            t.left(90);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Turtle Java squares Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73698122/turtle-java-squares-pyramid/73707326#73707326)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0):

This has the look of a problem that can be programmed recursively with less complication:

```
class Pyramid extends Turtle {
    public void construct(double base, int levels) {
        int blocks_per_base = levels * 2 - 1;
        
        this.construct_recursive(blocks_per_base, 1, base / blocks_per_base, levels);
    }

    public void construct_recursive(int width, int height, double block, int levels) {
        if (levels > 0) {
            this.rectangle(width, height, block);
            this.forward(block);
            this.construct_recursive(width - 2, height + 1, block, levels - 1);
        }
    }

    public void rectangle(int width, int height, double block) {
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            this.forward(width * block);
            this.left(90);
            this.forward(height * block);
            this.left(90);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pyramid pyramid = new Pyramid();
        pyramid.construct(200, 5);
    }
}
```

[image]